# Email Intent works some layouts but doesn't work some layouts

Tags: android

I want to connect gmail . My code works on one layout(one screen) but my code doesn't work on 4 layouts(views)

How can I fixed?

```
Button btn_mail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMail);
    btn_mail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String content="Aşağıda çeşitli ürünler yer almaktadır.Bu ürünlerin analizi bilgilerinin yapılıp,tarafımıza dönüş yapılmasını rica ediyoruz.\n"
                    +"Uludağ Gazoz 1lt-Cam Şişe\n"
                    +"Uludağ Gazoz 250ml-Plastik\n" +
                    "Uludağ Soda Premium 330ml\n"+"Üç ürün için analiz dökümantasyonu hazırlamanızı rica ediyoruz.\n"+"İyi Çalışmalar...";
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"m.keskin@uludag.com.tr"});
               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ÜRÜN GRUPLARI ANALİZi");

               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
               startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email"));

        }
    });
```

Comment: please show more details about the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works on every layout

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "Subject");

        String body = "Aşağıda çeşitli ürünler yer almaktadır.Bu ürünlerin analizi bilgilerinin yapılıp,tarafımıza dönüş yapılmasını rica ediyoruz.\n"
                    +"Uludağ Gazoz 1lt-Cam Şişe\n"
                    +"Uludağ Gazoz 250ml-Plastik\n" +
                    "Uludağ Soda Premium 330ml\n"+"Üç ürün için analiz dökümantasyonu hazırlamanızı rica ediyoruz.\n"+"İyi Çalışmalar...";emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,body);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```